# Storyboard layout not correct on iPad 2

Tags: ios, ipad, uistoryboard

I am trying to lay out objects on a Storyboard using the interface builder yet when I run the app on an iPad2, the layout is being messed up and objects are not appearing where they should. All the objects are there but they are being moved horizontally and not the same number of pixels! For instance, I have two ImageViews overlayed on one another (one is 100x100 and one is 75x75 centred within) but when the app is run on the iPad, they are both being moved horizontally across the screen by different distances!

I'd like to add screenshots but unfortunately I can't for privacy reasons.

I know it's vague but does anyone have any ideas on where to start looking to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too when I was first making an iPad app.

Try fiddling with some of the 'struts & springs' of the interface elements in the storyboard. To do this, select some of the interface elements, then on the right panel go to the size inspector and try some things with the 'Autosizing' rectangle.

[image: Size inspector XCode]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Thermometer, I will have a play around and see what happens!

Comment: Absolutely unhelpful. The answer basically says "Play around with it" and because the person asking the question did and happened on something that looks right he ticked it as the correct answer.

Comment: At least I'm getting him in the right direction :) If you have a better answer, feel free to post it!